# Openlayer - keep listening filter A while applying filter B

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have two filter on my map

- Filter A which filter my points by the feature's geometry of a polygon layer
- Filter B which filter my points by certain attribute

When I apply the filter A and then the filter B, the filter A isn't taken into account anymore.

I would like the filter A to be always running like : **if the layers are refreshing, it need to pass through the Filter A**

I tried with
layer.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function() {})
map.on('rendercomplete', e => {})

It does not work, any idea?

```js
//Base layer
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

//Point layer
var point =
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_hospitals_point&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: (feature) => {
            return new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 8,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "turquoise"
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'white',
                        width: 2
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })

    var point2 =
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_telecom_fibre_connection_point&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: (feature) => {
            return new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 8,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "darkblue"
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'white',
                        width: 2
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })


// The map
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 8,
        center: [255000, 6266791]
    }),
    layers: [
        osm,
        point,
        point2
    ]
});


let urlFilterLayer = "https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:departement&outputformat=application/json"

//filter layer
let filterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({})
});

//Ajout des couche de filtre après coup  
map.addLayer(filterLayer);

let dptGeometry;


$('#FilterB').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($('#FilterB').is(':checked')) {
        point.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_hospitals_point&CQL_FILTER=emergency LIKE 'yes'&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        point2.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_telecom_fibre_connection_point&CQL_FILTER=operator LIKE 'Orange'&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
    }else{
        point.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_hospitals_point&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        point2.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_telecom_fibre_connection_point&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
    }
});

function FilterA() {
    // For each layer if it is outside the selected area, apply no style
    for (let myLayer of map.getLayers().getArray()) {
        if (myLayer.K != undefined) {
                for (let element of myLayer.getSource().getFeatures()) {
                    if(!element.getGeometry() || !element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()) {
                        console.log(element);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (dptGeometry && 
                        dptGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(
                            element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
                        )
                    ){
                        element.setStyle(null)
                    }else {
                        element.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({}))
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}


    $('.radio').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($('#tous').is(':checked')) {
        // remove filter from area layer
        filterLayer.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        // For each layer (different from baselayer) reapply the default style
        for (let myLayer of map.getLayers().getArray()) {
            if (myLayer.K != undefined) {
                for (let element of myLayer.getSource().getFeatures()) {
                    element.setStyle(null)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        filterLayer.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_dep=" + $('input[name="dpt"]:checked').val(),
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        filterLayer.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function() {
            dptGeometry = filterLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry();
            FilterA();
        });
    }

});
```

```html
  <head>
        <!-- OpenLayer -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- TURF -->
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:600px;">
    
        <b>Filter A</b>
        <div id="radioIDFcontainer">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="tous" name="dpt" value="tous" checked>
            <label for="tous">All</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="75" name="dpt" value="75">
            <label for="75">Area 1</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="77" name="dpt" value="77">
            <label for="77">Area 2</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="78" name="dpt" value="78">
            <label for="78">Area 3</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="91" name="dpt" value="91">
            <label for="91">Area 4</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="92" name="dpt" value="92">
            <label for="92">Area 5</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="93" name="dpt" value="93">
            <label for="93">Area 6</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="94" name="dpt" value="94">
            <label for="94">Area 7</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="95" name="dpt" value="95">
            <label for="95">Area 8</label>
        </div> 

        </br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="FilterB" name="FilterB" value="FilterB">
        <label for="FilterB"><b>FilterB</b></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier if you make use of style functions to test the feature properties and the checkbox and geometries.  You do need to change sources or set styles on features.  You should also avoid creating new styles on each call of a style function, which takes up time and memory.

```js
//Base layer
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

let dptGeometry;

function filterA(feature) {
var geometry = feature.getGeometry()
return (
     geometry &&
     geometry.getCoordinates() &&
     (!dptGeometry || dptGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(geometry.getCoordinates()))
);
}

//Point layer
var pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 8,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: "turquoise"
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'white',
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        });

var point =
new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_hospitals_point&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: (feature) => {
        if (
           filterA(feature) &&
           (!$('#FilterB').is(':checked') || feature.get('emergency') == 'yes')
        ) {
            return pointStyle;
        }
    }
})

var point2Style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 8,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: "darkblue"
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'white',
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        });

var point2 =
new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "https://magosm.magellium.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=magosm:france_telecom_fibre_connection_point&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: (feature) => {
        if (
           filterA(feature) &&
           (!$('#FilterB').is(':checked') || feature.get('operator') == 'Orange')
        ) {
            return point2Style;
        }
    }
})


// The map
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
    zoom: 8,
    center: [255000, 6266791]
}),
layers: [
    osm,
    point,
    point2
]
});


let urlFilterLayer = "https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:departement&outputformat=application/json"

//filter layer
let filterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
}),
style: null
});

filterLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function(e) {
  e.feature.setId(e.feature.get('insee_dep'));
});

function setFilterA(e) {
dptGeometry = undefined;
if (!$('#tous').is(':checked')) {
  var dptFeature = filterLayer.getSource().getFeatureById($('input[name="dpt"]:checked').val());
  if (dptFeature) {
    dptGeometry = dptFeature.getGeometry();
  }
}
point.changed();
point2.changed();
}

filterLayer.getSource().on('featuresloadend', setFilterA);
$('.radio').on('change', setFilterA);

$('#FilterB').on('change', function(e) {
point.changed();
point2.changed();
});

//Ajout des couche de filtre après coup  
map.addLayer(filterLayer);
```

```html
  <head>
        <!-- OpenLayer -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- TURF -->
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:600px;">
    
        <b>Filter A</b>
        <div id="radioIDFcontainer">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="tous" name="dpt" value="tous" checked>
            <label for="tous">All</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="75" name="dpt" value="75">
            <label for="75">Area 1</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="77" name="dpt" value="77">
            <label for="77">Area 2</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="78" name="dpt" value="78">
            <label for="78">Area 3</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="91" name="dpt" value="91">
            <label for="91">Area 4</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="92" name="dpt" value="92">
            <label for="92">Area 5</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="93" name="dpt" value="93">
            <label for="93">Area 6</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="94" name="dpt" value="94">
            <label for="94">Area 7</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="95" name="dpt" value="95">
            <label for="95">Area 8</label>
        </div> 

        </br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="FilterB" name="FilterB" value="FilterB">
        <label for="FilterB"><b>FilterB</b></label>
```